# Remove characters elasticsearch

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to remove

> " "

from this message.

> <189>date=2018-03-02 time=00:50:16 devname="TEST"
>   devid="AAAAA" logid="0000000013" type="traffic"
>   subtype="forward" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1519980616
>   srcip=111.111.111 srcport=12345 srcintf="AAAAA"
>   srcintfrole="lan" dstip=AAAAAAA dstport=443 dstintf="port1"
>   dstintfrole="undefined" poluuid="52b23c9c-126c-51e8-84e1-38a5953285dc"
>   sessionid=57002479 proto=17 action="accept" policyid=62
>   policytype="policy" service="UDP_443" dstcountry="United States"
>   srccountry="Reserved" trandisp="snat" transip=123.123.123.123
>   transport=55699 duration=181 sentbyte=4928 rcvdbyte=5026 sentpkt=9
>   rcvdpkt=10 appcat="unscanned"

I have this filter:

```
grok {
  match => ["message", "%{SYSLOG5424PRI:syslog_index}%{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
  overwrite => [ "message" ]

  tag_on_failure => [ "failure" ]
}

kv { }
```

Comment: Use [mutate with gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub). But you'll have problems when the value between quotes will be more than one word.

Comment: do you want to remove all the double quotes or just any empty double quotes?